# how to plot one barplot with three stacks for series of distribution?

Tags: r, plot, stack

I have one series of data

```
x<-rnorm(1000)
```

i need to plot one horizontal barplot with 15%, 70% and 15% of data in three stacks as shown in image.

[image]

How can i plot this in R?

Answer (score 2):

```
barplot(table(cut(x, breaks=quantile(x, probs=c(0,0.15, 0.85, 1) ) )  ) )
```

[image]

This is a horizontal plot (that I would not call a "stacked barplot"

```
plot(x=x, y=rep(1,length(x)) , type="n")
segments( x0=c( min(z), quantile(z, probs=c(0,0.15, 0.85) ) ), 
             x1 =quantile(z, probs=c(0,0.15, 0.85, 1) ) , 
             y0=rep(1, 4), y1=rep(1,4) , col=c("red", "green", "blue"), lwd=30, lend=10)
```

Comment: @AnandaMahto, How to control its width?

Comment: The `as.matrix` call does nothing. Contingency tables are matrices.

Comment: @user15662: If you want a histogram , i.e. a plot where the area represents the counts, you should use one of the histogram functions. You asked for a barplot, so I gave you one. Or maybe you do not want a barplot?

Comment: @DWin I  need stacked barplot as suggested by AnandaMahto but i need to control its width.

Comment: Define what you mean by width of this thing that I do not think of as a "stacked barplot". It is the vertical or the horizontal dimension?

Comment: I didn't mean for you to delete your answer. I think it is better than mine. I just was hoping you would stop using `as.matrix` on  `table`-objects.

Comment: @DWin, what's the alternative in this case? `class(x1)` from my answer would return `table`, and if I didn't want to use `as.matrix`, I would have to use `t(t(x1))` to get the result that it seems the OP is looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a worked example:

```
x1 <- table(cut(x, breaks = quantile(x, probs = c(0,0.15, 0.85, 1))))

png(filename="~/test.png", width = 8, height = 2.5, units="in", res = 72)
barplot(
  as.matrix(x1), horiz = TRUE, 
  col = c("lightblue", "yellow", "palegreen"),
  axes = FALSE)
axis(1, at = c(0, cumsum(x1)), labels = c(0, 15, 85, 100))
dev.off()
```

This will create a png file named "test.png" in your working directory that looks like this.

[image]

Comment: I say again. A contingency table in R _IS_ a matrix.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. I m plotting for some other distribution using 25, 50 and 25, but i get following error message. Error in cut.default(x, breaks = quantile(x, probs = c(0, 0.25, 0.75,  : 
  'breaks' are not unique

Comment: I m using one series of 1200 values in which 1000 are '1' only.

Comment: I used x1 <- table(cut(x, breaks = quantile(x, probs = c(0,0.25, 0.75, 1))))

Comment: I don't get the error you show. Please verify. You may want to start from scratch and see if the error persists.

Comment: Right. Because if you run just `quantile(x, probs = c(0, .25, .75, 1))`, you'll see that 1 is in the 25th and 75th percentile.

Comment: So this cannot be used here?

Comment: @user15662, not that I can see. Sorry!